# How can I filter a response in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, object

I need to filter some data from a big complex object which is received as a response to a function.

```
function showchat() {
  dispatch(fetchChats())
    .then((res) => {
      document.write(JSON.stringify(res));
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

`fetchChats` is a function that provides me a object response as:

```
[
  {
    "id": 13,
    "type": "dual",
    "createdAt": "2022-11-01T18:42:08.487Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-11-01T18:42:08.487Z",
    "ChatUser": {
      "chatId": 13,
      "userId": 72,
      "createdAt": "2022-11-01T18:42:08.499Z",
      "updatedAt": "2022-11-01T18:42:08.499Z"
    },
    "Users": [
      {
        "avtar": "http://127.0.0.1:3000/male.svg",
        "id": 71,
        "firstName": "dhruv",
        "lastName": "parmar",
        "email": "dhruvdp.js@gmail.com",
        "password": "$2b$10$VYQdhqz2ig3NP/8tbJtGHu9kWuNsym4oFobpdy9QLuTJPzQSBq0TG",
        "gender": "male",
        "createdAt": "2022-11-01",
        "updatedAt": "2022-11-01",
        "ChatUser": {
          "chatId": 13,
          "userId": 71,
          "createdAt": "2022-11-01T18:42:08.499Z",
          "updatedAt": "2022-11-01T18:42:08.499Z"
        },
        "status": "offline"
      }
    ],
    "Messages": [
      {
        "message": "Bhai kaisa hai?",
        "id": 13,
        "type": "text",
        "chatId": 13,
        "fromuserId": 71,
        "createdAt": "2022-11-01T18:42:08.505Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-11-01T18:42:08.505Z",
        "User": {
          "avtar": "http://127.0.0.1:3000/male.svg",
          "id": 71,
          "firstName": "dhruv",
          "lastName": "parmar",
          "email": "dhruvdp.js@gmail.com",
          "password": "$2b$10$VYQdhqz2ig3NP/8tbJtGHu9kWuNsym4oFobpdy9QLuTJPzQSBq0TG",
          "gender": "male",
          "createdAt": "2022-11-01",
          "updatedAt": "2022-11-01"
        }
      },
      {
        "message": "Badiya bhai tu bata",
        "id": 14,
        "type": "text",
        "chatId": 13,
        "fromuserId": 72,
        "createdAt": "2022-11-01T18:42:08.505Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-11-01T18:42:08.505Z",
        "User": {
          "avtar": "http://127.0.0.1:3000/male.svg",
          "id": 72,
          "firstName": "Harshit",
          "lastName": "rajpal",
          "email": "harshit@gmail.com",
          "password": "$2b$10$pGZ./D2axPY4WE.raJW0eOSIX11RluimkIMQ7bDwWgYBsyzhrBFtu",
          "gender": "male",
          "createdAt": "2022-11-01",
          "updatedAt": "2022-11-01"
        }
      },
      {
        "message": "Bass apki kripa",
        "id": 15,
        "type": "text",
        "chatId": 13,
        "fromuserId": 71,
        "createdAt": "2022-11-01T18:42:08.505Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-11-01T18:42:08.505Z",
        "User": {
          "avtar": "http://127.0.0.1:3000/male.svg",
          "id": 71,
          "firstName": "dhruv",
          "lastName": "parmar",
          "email": "dhruvdp.js@gmail.com",
          "password": "$2b$10$VYQdhqz2ig3NP/8tbJtGHu9kWuNsym4oFobpdy9QLuTJPzQSBq0TG",
          "gender": "male",
          "createdAt": "2022-11-01",
          "updatedAt": "2022-11-01"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I need to filter all the 'message' from this object but I am comfused

[image: If I didn't convert the res into string it looks something like this]

Comment: Well, the data is an array with one object with a nested `Messages` property. So `const messages = data[0].Messages` or `const [{ Messages }] = data;` perhaps. If you have more than one object you'll need to use `map` or `flatMap` to flush them out.

Comment: Have you tried with [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, you want to filter the message, but filter it based on what?

Do you mean you just want to extract the messages?

This one extracts with ids for reference

```
const messages = obj.map(x => {return { parentId: x.id,  messages: x.Messages.map(x => {return {id: x.id, messages: x.message}})}})
```

This one extracts just messages for each Chat object

```
const messages = obj.map(x => x.Messages.map(x => x.message))
```

And this one flattens it

```
const messages = obj.map(x => x.Messages.map(x => x.message)).flat()
```